# Java framework to store relational data in Redis

Tags: java, architecture, redis, nosql

Is there a Java framework to store relational data in Redis? Something for simple use cases e.g:

- 1 article to N comments – sorted by comment creation date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple options you have:

1. jOHM (Object Hash Mapper, https://github.com/xetorthio/johm)
2. Hibernate OGM Redis (5.0.Beta, tech preview https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/5.0/reference/en-US/html/ch15.html)
3. Spring Data Redis Key-Value (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/pull/156, https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-keyvalue-redis)

jOHM is quite mature whereas Hibernate OGM Redis is quite new.

HTH, Mark

**Update**

- Added the link to the Spring Data Redis Key-Value PR

Comment: I wonder whether jOHM is still alive and is yes, which forks is the right one. Spring seems to be promising. Thank you @mp911de so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [good article](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-redisson-live-object-object-hash-mappi) about Redis based `Live Objects` introduced in [Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework.